# how to create three different environments in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I want to deploy a public facing web project on aws for which I have setup ec2 for front end and another ec2 for backend (leave discussion about hpa and other services etc for now).  I have to integrate jenkin ci/cd pipeline with this. The setup have 3 environment (staging, production and development with 3 individual databases). My query is how to setup these 3 individual env? Do I need to create 3 different individual projects in aws  including frontend ec2, backend ec2 and cicd pipeline? code will be committed in all the env by developer manually and respective cicd pipeline will take care of rest in the respective environment? OR there would be one infrastructure with separate databases per env and common cicd.